# XML import of nested classes with space between them

Tags: class, google-sheets, space, xml-import

I am using XMLimport to import various bits of information from a coinmarketcap.com page into a Google sheet. It all works perfectly, accept when I come across what look like two classes appearing within a span tag. This is used to show the 24hr Bitcoin price change.

In this case the class is called "sc-15yy2pl-0 gEePkg". But when I try to use this it doesn't work and returns an #N/A instead. This is the code I am trying:

`=IMPORTXML("coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//span[@class='sc-15yy2pl-0 gEePkg']")`

I know their are API's and other things that can do this, but I am not a developer. I am a mere mortal doing my best to learn the IMPORTXML feature. If anyone knows how I should treat these two classes when they have a space between them, I would be most grateful.

Comment: pls, give the expected output

Comment: So it should just pull in a percentage figure like "5.6%" that is being calculated on the page.

Answer (score 0):

With adding `https://`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//span[@class='sc-15yy2pl-0 gEePkg']")
```

or

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//span[@class='sc-15yy2pl-0 gEePkg']"),1,2)
```

or

```
=query(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//span[@class='sc-15yy2pl-0 gEePkg']"),"select Col2,Col4 limit 1 ")
```

or

```
=value(textjoin("",,query(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//span[@class='sc-15yy2pl-0 gEePkg']"),"select Col2,Col4 limit 1 ")))
```

[image]

Comment: None of these above options work.

Comment: Everything works for me! Maybe you have been banned for a while due to many questions on the site? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gO8-YHrVzyUgGKwqo3H_Fd8E0ZfyRrIvf06f3SYXNW4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try the last proposal.

Comment: Hey I apologise, yours do work! I copied and pasted from your spreadsheet over to mine, and it's perfect. I'm not sure why it didn't work this first time I copied from this thread. 

Can you please educate me - what is the "1,2" you added to the end, and the "select Col2,Col4 limit 1 "?

Comment: `=index(_______,1,2)` means that I select first row and 2nd column only from the global result.